# I am trying to make a method just like lastIndexOf() in class ArrayList but I am facing some issues finding the last index of an element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

```
public int lastIndexOf(E o) {
        int res = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < size() ; i++) {
            if(o.equals(this.elementData[i]) ) { 
                return i;  
            }
        }
        return res; 
    }

}
```

I am not able to return the last index of an element.
Say we have `String tmp [] = {"EECS", "2030", "Class","Example about", "Array", "List", "Array", null, null, null};`
Here, I am checking the last index for element `Array` in `tmp` but my code returns  the first index of element occurrence. How do I approach for the last index ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: change your loop to itertate from the end of your list to the beginning: `for(int i = (size() - 1); i >= 0 ; i--)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change `return i` to `res = i;` because on first item found the method will return the value and end it but you need to iterate till the last element inside array and return the index of that at the end of method :

```
public int lastIndexOf(E o) {
    int res = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if (o.equals(this.elementData[i])) {
            res = i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

or you can try to check the index of value from end of array and if the element found then return the index else at the end of loop the `res` will be returned which is equal to `-1` means not found :

```
public int lastIndexOf(E o) {
    int res = -1;
    for (int i = (size() -1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (o.equals(this.elementData[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should start your iteration from the end instead, so that when you do find your object it will definitely be the last one and you won't need to continue iterating through the rest of the array.

```
public int lastIndexOf(E o) {
    int res = -1;
    for (int i = size() -1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (o.equals(this.elementData[i])) 
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```